# allow acces to files in cpanel only from my application

Tags: android, json, security

I have made an android application in which it reads some JSON data from cpanel using a JSON library, but next I realised that someone has access to these files and they use it in their website which leads to a lot of bandwidth consumption. In fact, anyone can read my files if they find the direct URL which can be caught easily using a software like Wireshark .

**These files are supposed to be hidden** and I want to block any access not coming from my android application. I used to do that by allowing the user agent only from .htaccess but that's not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your situation, you want to hide your **API** keys:

Please go through this tutorial in order to get more detailed information about API key security.

[How to hide your API Key in Android](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-hide-your-api-key-in-android-600583/)

---